# Change the highlight color in multiple places at once

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365

I have a set of places within a document file, which I would like to keep highlighted, but I do not want this feature to appear while printing. 
I am interested in a convenient way which would enable me to turn on / off this highlight for all places within the text.

I suppose that one of the `field` functions should solve this issue, but I am unable to find out which one would work.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 3 ways you could do this.

1. Manually with and Advanced Find and Replace, and you'd setup the search to look for the Highlight color. If you also added bookmarks to the highlighted words/phrases, that would help you put the highlights back into the document after printing.
2. There's a free add-in to Word called AuthorTec Find'n Highlight, do a web search to read about it. It works from stored Words/Phrases and add's or removes highlighting on the text it finds.
3. Custom VBA solution that fully automates the manual method that I mentioned in item 1. It could search for the Highlight color, add the bookmark, turn off the Highlight color, send the document to print, search the document for the temporary bookmarks and replace them with the chosen Highlight color.

Comment: I agree that all points will work, however, it is simple task...
Thus points #2 and #3 are in my opinion slight overkills compared to the problem.